# va-args not resolving correctly

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have the following function:

```
void Register(Data* _pData, uint32 _Line, const char* _pFile, ...)
{
   va_list Args;
   va_start(Args, _pFile);
   for(uint i = 0;i m_NumFloats; ++i)
   {
      _pData->m_Floats[i] = va_arg(Args, fp32);
   }
   va_end(Args);
}
```

Which is called by the macro:

```
#define REG(_Name, ...)\
{\
   if(s_##_Name##_Data.m_Enabled)
      Register(&s_##_Name##_Data, __LINE__, __FILE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
}\
```

With the usage:

```
REG(Test, (fp32)0.42f);
```

The Data-struct looks like:

```
struct Data
{
   int m_NumFloats;
   fp32 m_Floats[4];
}
```

The creation-macro of Data creates the static `Data g_YourName_Data` and initializes it correctly with a maximum of 4 m_NumFloats.

The va_arg call resolves to 0.0. s_Test_Data exists and the Register-function is called appropriate. va-list just simply won't let me resolve the first argument into the float that I passed it into. Is there anything specific that I'm missing?

Comment: What is `_Name_Data`? Why are you declaring `_Name` parameter in your macro, when your macro definition does not use `_Name` anywhere at all? What is `##` doing in front of `__VA_ARGS__`?

Comment: There is no `_Name_Data`. It's a macro using `_Name` to find a statically declared object which in this case expands to `_Test_Data`. So the macro does use `_Name`. The `##` Is used to strip the `,` if no actual extra parameters are passed.

Comment: @AndreyT "What is ## doing in front of `__VA_ARGS__`?" - it is making it possible for a variadic macro to receive zero arguments.

Comment: @H2CO3: Could you elaborate a bit on that? What difference does it make (compared to the same thing without the `##`)? And how will it help with the issue of trailing `,`?

Comment: @AndreyT This is a special construct, I'm not sure whether or not it is standard. The preprocessor will elimate the trailing comma if `__VA_ARG__` is preceded by the token pasting operator and there are no variadic arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
#define REG(_Name, ...)\
{\
   if(s_##_Name_Data.m_Enabled)\
      Register(&s_##_Name_Data, __LINE__, __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__);\
}
```

Get rid of the token-pasting operator.  You we're also missing a '\' in your macro (maybe a copy-n-paste error?).

Also, use `va_arg()`, not `va_args()`.  And I'm not sure if you meant for `_Name` to be `_Name_Data` or the other way around.

Finally, I assumed that `fp32` was an alias for `float`; GCC had this to say to me:

```
C:\TEMP\test.c:22: warning: `fp32' is promoted to `double' when passed through `...'
C:\TEMP\test.c:22: warning: (so you should pass `double' not `fp32' to `va_arg')
C:\TEMP\test.c:22: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
```

You should heed that warning. The program does crash for me if I do not.

Comment: The `, ## __VA_ARGS__` thing is a GCC extension which makes the comma go away if `__VA_ARGS__` expands to no tokens (i.e. if REG() is called with only one argument).  In *this case* it's inappropriate because Register() must receive at least one anonymous argument, and you'd like that to be a compile error rather than garbage at runtime, but it's not automatically wrong.

Comment: @Zack - thanks for that information.  I knew the GCC had a way to deal with empty `__VAR_ARGS__`, but didn't remember that that was it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael, and sorry for the copy-and-paste errors. I'll edit the post to make it correct. I'm not getting any such warnings. The real code handles the case where no va-args are present, the number of arguments expected are defined earlier.Should you really append an extra `\ ` on the last line of the macro? I'm quite certain that you don't need that (since I have several macros which don't have it and it would have caused some compiler errors if it didn't). `_Name` is inserted into the identifier that we're accessing. In this case the identifier would become `s_Test_Data`.

Comment: Oh, I'm using microsoft's compiler and not GCC.

Comment: Changing it into reading a `double` made it work though! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You definitely don't want a backslash on the last line of the macro, it'll suck whatever's on the *next* line of source into the macro as well.  Probably right now that's a blank line and so it's harmless, but then someone comes along and decides that the code would look better without the blank line and hilarity ensues.

Comment: @Simon: "I'm using Microsoft's compiler and not GCC" - I was really, really surprised that GCC diagnosed that problem in a warning.  I doubt that it's something I would have figured out on my (at least not without quite a debugging effort). This is one reason I try to compile snippets with problems using several compilers. Kudos to GCC for diagnosing that.

Comment: @Michael: Indeed, GCC tend to warn about a lot more than MSVC so I should probably try to set up my build-system to work with GCC as well just to catch more errors. Thanks again!